# Is there a <wbr> equivalent tag to affect whole sentences instead of just single words?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, display

The HTML tag `<wbr>` breaks a word in case of word-wrap due to a small screen.

But is there a tag that could be used in order to break and wrap the text of a sentence on a specific point in case of a small screen?

The CSS tag on my question is probably irrelevant, but I thought that maybe someone could have implemented a solution using CSS.

Comment: Couldn't you still use `wbr`? I may not be understanding your question correctly.

Comment: Can't you just use <br/> ? Not sure if I understand your question either.

Comment: Imagine for example a sentence of 10 words and a wbr tag in the middle of the sentence. Depending on the screen size, on one device there are going to be i.e. 9 words on the first row and one on the second. In another device there may be 8 words on the 1st row and 2 on the second.. etc..

Comment: br and br/ split the sentence by default and not when the page is loaded on a device with smaller screen.

Comment: You could add a class that hides it on larger displays.

Comment: That is a good idea but sounds like a lot of work for something relatively simple. And I guess it includes the process of reading the display dimension  in order to decide to hide the br tag or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wbr.mobile {
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    wbr.mobile {
        display: initial;
    }
}
```

Just add the class `mobile` wherever you'd like to use this.

---

EDIT FROM ASKER:

The code that worked for me is the following:

```
br {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  br {
      display: initial;
  }
}

<p class="br">There is nothing impossible<br> to him who will try.</p>
```

I changed wbr to br because as I explained in my question I wanted to simulate the effects of wbr on whole sentences and not just words. And I don't think media-queries could change the behavior or an HTML tag.

And secondly, I used just br and not br.mobile because whenever I tried to reference back to br.mobile using class="br mobile" I wasn't able. Probable my mistake in this one.

Also this way of solution affects every `<br>` in the page, so I guess there must be more refinement to be done with IDs in order to affect specific paragraphs.

Comment: Great idea! thank you for introducing me to media-queries, I was totally unaware of them. Yet for my case I had to make some changes in order to work, so I am going to make an edit (only to append my version) before I accept the answer.

Comment: Ok, hopefully it helps! There's some real cool CSS features that are relatively new (<5-10 years old).

Answer (score 0):

I typically use [Non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) to control where my sentences break.  Experiment by changing the browser window size.

```html
<div>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy sleeping dog, only&nbsp;to&nbsp;find&nbsp;that&nbsp;the cat&nbsp;had&nbsp;jumped&nbsp;over&nbsp;the&nbsp;moon.</div>
```